# the category buttons are redirecting me to the home screen on the front end

Tags: magento-1.9, category

On the front end, I have categories that people can click to redirect them to a specific item category. However, whenever I click on the button it redirects me to the home screen, not the item category.

I have already flushed the cache and refreshed it as well. I have also re indexed it.

Comment: can you please add more detail like how created that category? If you have created using programming then can you please add your code. Thanks

Comment: i did it through the back end of magento